# PexObserve only records 255 characters

Tags: visual-studio-2012, pex, intellitest

I am using Pex from the command line to find input values for test case generation.
I use PexObserve to record certain values during execution. 
One of the values that I want to record is an XML-String.

However, when parsing the XML I receive "malformed XML" exceptions, since Pex only writes the first 255 characters into the log.

Is there a way to record the full XML string? or does PexObserve have a different type that will let me record longer texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here, in case somebody at any point has the same issue.
I've found a solution that helped me.

Unfortunately the 255 character limit is set internally in `static readonly` fields.
Therefore I needed to use reflection.
My solution works by including the following line in the PUT:

```
typeof(Microsoft.Pex.Framework.PexObserve.ValueWriterManager).GetField("MaxWrittenElements").SetValue(null, 1000);
```

Replace the `1000` with any value you like.

BUT: remember that this is a quick-fix solution, that might not work for you.
It may have unwanted side-effects. You're also changing the number of List elements that are written, and perhaps other things.